# How to get the result of a quadratic equation with negative root in c ++?

Tags: c++, math

I am trying to obtain the result of a quadratic equation with negative root, but the result that I obtain is not the same when I do the operation on paper, also the result is not the same only with negative roots when it is the opposite, it works perfectly.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, b, c;

    double x1, x2;
    cout << "Quadratic Formula" << endl;
    cout << "    -b + sqrt(b ^ 2) - 4ac" << endl;
    cout << "x = -----------------------" << endl;
    cout << "              2a" << endl;
    cout << "" << endl;
    
    cout << "a Value: " << endl;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "b Value: " << endl;
    cin >> b;
    cout << "c Value: " << endl;    
    cin >> c;

    double sqRoot, det;

    det = b * b - 4 * a * c;

    if(det < 0)
    {
    
       sqRoot = sqrt(det * -1); //minus per minus = plus so it's possible to calculate the sqrt of
                                //the negative number
       x1 = (-b + sqRoot)/ 2 * a; 
       x2 = (-b - sqRoot)/ 2 * a;
    
       cout << "value of x1: " << x1 << " i"<< endl;
    
       cout << "Value of x2: " << x2 << " i"<< endl;        
   }
   else
   {
       sqRoot = sqrt(det);
    
       x1 = (-b + sqRoot)/ 2 * a; 
       x2 = (-b - sqRoot)/ 2 * a;
    
       cout << "Value of x1: " << x1 << endl;
    
       cout << "Value of x2: " << x2 << endl;
   }

}
```

Comment: If you get `-nan` then that's because you can't have a square root of negative numbers in C++.

Comment: Typo: `/ 2 * a` --> `/ (2 * a)`?

Comment: Yeap, operator precedence.

Comment: Also you might need to operate with complex numbers (as in std::complex) or keep the imaginary part separately.

Comment: When the roots are complex, the real part is `-b/(2*a)` and the imaginary part is `sqRoot/(2*a)`. You can't add the real and imaginary parts into an entirely imaginary number.

Comment: When delta is negative it doesn't mean that roots have ONLY imagine component only. It means imagine part is none zero. So basically you print invalid result for this case. Note also C++ standard library supports complex numbers.

Comment: if you can use math lib to calculate ***sqrt*** then unse ***abs*** to avoid the if - else...

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/f9berG

Comment: @G.M. I already did the operation as you suggest, but I don't see any difference when the root is positive, anyway I think it is clearer to put the multiplication in parentheses.

Comment: @AdrianRoman I din't know about the `std::complex`, I think that's maybe what I need.
@molbdnilo Very good, thanks for the guidance.
@MarekR no, I mean, it is not printing invalid result like NaN or something like that, it is printing wrong result and thanks for the solution, I gonna keep trying figure it out another solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is opeartion priority.

You should have a parenthesis in the following lines:

```cpp
        x1 = (-b + sqRoot)/ (2 * a);
        x2 = (-b - sqRoot)/ (2 * a);
```

instead of

```cpp
        x1 = (-b + sqRoot)/ 2 * a;
        x2 = (-b - sqRoot)/ 2 * a;
```

The second problem is your division using `int` variables.

The code shall be like the following:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, b, c;

    double x1, x2;
    cout << "Quadratic Formula" << endl;
    cout << "    -b + sqrt(b ^ 2) - 4ac" << endl;
    cout << "x = -----------------------" << endl;
    cout << "              2ac" << endl;
    cout << "" << endl;

    cout << "a Value: " << endl;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "b Value: " << endl;
    cin >> b;
    cout << "c Value: " << endl;
    cin >> c;

    double sqRoot, det;

    det = b*b - 4*a*c;

    // complex roots
    if(det < 0)
    {
        sqRoot = sqrt(det *(-1)); //minus per minus = plus so it's possible to calculate the sqrt of
        //the negative number
        
        // HERE ALSO BUT SOLUTIONS ARE COMPLEX SO YOU NEED TO SHOW IMAGINARY PART AND REAL PART
        // x1 = (-b + sqRoot)/ (2 * a); // ==>x=-b/(double)(2*a)  and y =i*sqRoot/(double)(2*a)
        // x2 = (-b - sqRoot)/ (2 * a);//==>x=-b/(double)(2*a)  and y =-i*sqRoot/(double)(2*a)
        cout << "value of x1: " << std::setprecision (4)<<  (-b/(double)(2*a)) << "+"<<sqRoot/(2*a)<<*"i"<< endl;
        cout << "Value of x2: " << std::setprecision (4)<< (-b/(double)(2*a)) << -sqRoot/(2*a)<<"i"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        sqRoot = sqrt(det);
        // ALSO HERE
        x1 = (-b + sqRoot)/ (2 * a);
        x2 = (-b - sqRoot)/ (2 * a);
        cout << "Value of x1: " << x1 << endl;
        cout << "Value of x2: " << x2 << endl;
    }
}
```

the results can be tested below:

```
3x^2 + 4x + 2 = 0
```

gives for the execution:

```sh
Quadratic Formula
    -b + sqrt(b ^ 2) - 4ac
x = -----------------------
              2ac

a Value:
3
b Value:
4
c Value:
2
value of x1: -0.6667+0.4714i
Value of x2: -0.6667-0.4714i
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `std::complex`:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<complex>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double a = 1.0;
    double b = 4.0;
    double c = 5.0;

    double det = b * b - 4.0 * a * c;
    
    auto sqRoot = sqrt(std::complex<double>(det));
    auto x1 = (-b + sqRoot) / (2.0 * a); 
    auto x2 = (-b - sqRoot) / (2.0 * a);

    cout << "value of x1: " << x1 << endl; // (-2,1)
    cout << "value of x2: " << x2 << endl; // (-2,-1)    
}
```

Comment: It's clearly a good solution, but it doesn't work for me as the data type `auto` throws the following error: `variableName is not a type`, I solved that by declaring all variables with `auto` to  `std :: complex < double> `.

Comment: Your compiler must be quite old if it doesn't know `auto`...

Comment: Yes I tried it with another one and it works, I should update the one I use.